# how to get place number of specific check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of check boxes made by JS with same class that every each of them is inside a separated div. i need to find out the place number of specific check box between all same class named check boxes inside a div.

For example

```html
<div class="div_a1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a1">title1
</div>
<div class="div_a2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a2">title2
</div>
<div class="div_a1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a1">title3
</div>
<div class="div_a4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a4">title4
</div>
<div class="div_a2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a2">title5
</div>
<div class="div_a3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a3">title6
</div>
<div class="div_a1"> <-- user this div is clicked
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a1">title7
</div>
<div class="div_a4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a4">title8
</div>
<div class="div_a5">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a5">title9
</div>
```

And I can get the number "3", because I clicked on the div element of the third checkbox named class "div_a1".

Comment: What do you mean by "_place number of the checkbox_"? Do you want to get its parent element or its index number if all checkboxes are selected using `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')`?

Answer (score 1):

//As you mentioned, you are generating your checkbox using Js.So I would have //used
some loop.for exp: for loop

for (var i = 0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {

```
    var htmltemp = '<div class="div_a1"><input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick="getNum('+(i+1)+');" class="a1" >title1</div>';

    $('.SuperParentDiv').append(htmltemp)

}
```

//and can define the function

function getNum(rowid)

```js
//As you mentioned, you are generating your checkbox using Js.So I would have //used some loop.for exp: for loop

var itemlist = ArrayOfYourDivAndCheckBoxRows[];

for (var i = 0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {

        var htmltemp = '<div class="div_a1"><input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick="getNum('+(i+1)+');" class="a1" >title1</div>';

        $('.SuperParentDiv').append(htmltemp)

    }


//and can define the function 

function getNum(rowid)
{
    console.log("div" + rowid + "was clicked");

}
```

{
console.log("div" + rowid + "was clicked");

}

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick event listener to each input field and pass their place number as a parameter to the function as shown below

```
 <div class="div_a1">
     <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(1) class="a1" >title1
</div>
<div class="div_a2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(1) class="a2">title2
</div>
<div class="div_a1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(2) class="a1">title3
</div>
<div class="div_a4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(1) class="a4">title4
</div>
<div class="div_a2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(2) class="a2">title5
</div>
<div class="div_a3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(1) class="a3" >title6
</div>
<div class="div_a1"> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(3) class="a1">title7
</div>
<div class="div_a4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(2) class="a4" >title8
</div>
<div class="div_a5">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" onclick=getNum(1) class="a5" >title9
</div>
  </body>
  
  
  <script>
 function getNum(num){
console.log(num)
 }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it in this case:

```js
$('input').on('change', function(){

  // using the input class
  console.log( $(this).attr('class').replace( /^\D+/g, '') )
  
  // using the div class
  console.log( $(this).parent().attr('class').replace( /^\D+/g, '') )
  
  // using the title text
  console.log( $(this).parent().text().replace( /^\D+/g, '') )
  
  // using the index of the parent div from all divs with a class starting with "div_a"
  console.log( $(this).parent().parent().children('div[class^=div_a]').index($(this).parent()) + 1 )
})
```

```css
body .as-console-wrapper {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    max-height: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_a1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a1">title1
</div>
<div class="div_a2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a2">title2
</div>
<div class="div_a3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a3">title3
</div>
<div class="div_a4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a4">title4
</div>
<div class="div_a5">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a5">title5
</div>
<div class="div_a6">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a6">title6
</div>
<div class="div_a7">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a7">title7
</div>
<div class="div_a8">
  <input type="checkbox" name="aaa" class="a8">title8
</div>
```